# Tesseract c# : Find nothing in my case

Tags: c#, tesseract

I've add the C# wrapper for tesseract : [TesseractEngine](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract)

I've two types of images to read :

[image]

And the second type (one letter only) :

[image]

But in both case, Tesseract return empty string.

Here is my code (found in docs) :

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        var testImagePath = @"C:\plate\ExtractLicensePlate-0.jpg";
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            testImagePath = args[0];
        }

        try
        {
            using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
            {
                engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");

                using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(testImagePath))
                {
                    using (var page = engine.Process(img))
                    {
                        var text = page.GetText();//<-- empty :(

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Maybe I miss an option or something else?

EDIT : I've try this kind but no success to :

[image]

EDIT 2 : I've try Gray and Black and White and Tesseract Give me : EEEEEEE

[image]

I don't know what I can do better... :

Comment: From my experience with tesseract, color images make it go crazy. If you convert it to grayscale and increase the contrast of the image the results should be better, I even converted those to b&w and that's how I got the best results (if the problem is on the image)

Comment: i've already test and nothing better.If you have a running solution, can you test the 'E' image and tell me?

Comment: Sorry, I have no working project right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would recommend converting the image to greyscale
2. Try setting the `PageSegMode` to `SingleChar` or `SingleWord`

   ```
      using (var page = engine.Process(img, PageSegMode.SingleChar))
      {
          var text = page.GetText();
      }
   ```

Comment: Now, it return false results. I've edit my question.

Comment: @Portekoi at this point, the problem is probably with your training data.  Look into training a dataset based on your images/font https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract